# customize jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have the following code:

```
<form id="reg_form_pay" class="fancy_form" action="" method="POST">
  <div class="wrap_input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p class="inp_label">Firstname:</p>
    <i> </i>
    <input id="pay_firstname" type="text" value="" name="FirstName" style="width: 157px;">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p class="inp_label">Surname:</p>
    <i> </i>
    <input id="pay_lastname" type="text" value="" name="Surname" style="width: 157px;">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 34px;">
    <p class="inp_label">E-mail:</p>
    <i> </i>
    <input id="pay_email" type="text" value="" name="Email" style="width: 157px;">
  </div>
  <div class="wrap_input" style="margin-top: 34px;">
    <p class="inp_label">Phone:</p>
    <i> </i>
    <input id="pay_phone" type="text" value="" name="PhoneNumber" style="width: 157px;">
  </div>
</form>
```

And validation:

```
$("#reg_form_pay").validate({
            rules: {
                Email: { required: true, email: true, checkEmail: true },
                PhoneNumber: { required: true, checkPhoneNumber: true },
                FirstName: { required: true },
                Surname: { required: true }
            }, 
        });
```

By default, validator write `label` when validation is false. I dont't want add element with error description. I want to add class `error` to parent `div` with class `wrap_input`. How can I say to validator to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: check the validator plugin documentation, they usually have well documented explanation on how to do one or two things, if you want further help please link the specific plugin your using

Comment: Out of interest, what are the `<i> </i>` tags for, and why not use `<label>` tags for the labels, instead of `<p>` tags?

Comment: The `<i>` use for rounded input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the options sent to `validate` would work:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $.each(errorList,function(i,e){
        $(e.element).parents('.wrap_input').addClass('error');
    });                   
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nqp8J/